# onActivityResult() returns to First fragment of activity while selecting image

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-activity

I have Main Activity with Navigation drawer. In that I have edit button which open Edit Fragment. The user selected image from Camera or gallery should be displayed in ImageView.

Here the issue I am facing is I can select the image successfully and it also returns the image in onActivityResult(). But it exits the fragment and gets redirected to Main activity fragment after returning back from Camera or Gallery.

I am required to set image in ImageView and stay in the same fragment after onActivityResult() is called.

Here is my code:

**EditProfileFragment.java**

```
public class EditProfileFragment extends Fragment {

    RadioButton radioMale, radioFemale;
    Calendar birthDataCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    CustomEditText etBirthDate;
    CustomClearableEditText etName, etNumber, etAddress;
    CircleImageView civProfile, civChoose;
    ImageView ivBack;
    Bundle extra;
    byte[] byteArray;
    Bitmap bitmap;
    private static final int REQUEST_CAMERA = 55;
    private static final int SELECT_FILE = 66;


  @Nullable
  @Override
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_profile, container, false);
    return view;
}

  @Override
  public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    etName = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_et_name);
    etNumber = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_et_contact_no);
    etAddress = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_et_address);
    radioMale = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_radio_male);
    radioFemale = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_radio_female);
    etBirthDate = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_et_birth_date);
    civProfile = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_civ_profile);
    civChoose = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_civ_choose);
    ivBack = view.findViewById(R.id.edit_profile_iv_back);

        civChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            final CharSequence[] options = {"Camera", "Choose from Gallery", "Cancel"};

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.AlertDialogCustom);
            builder.setTitle("Add Photo from..");
            builder.setItems(options, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                @Override

                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    if (options[item].equals("Camera")) {
                        Intent cameraIntent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                        cameraIntent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_SCREEN_ORIENTATION, ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
                        startActivityForResult(cameraIntent, REQUEST_CAMERA);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Choose from Gallery")) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
                        startActivityForResult(intent, SELECT_FILE);
                    } else if (options[item].equals("Cancel")) {
                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
            builder.show();
        }
    });

    final DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener date = new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

        @Override
        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear,
                              int dayOfMonth) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            birthDataCalendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
            birthDataCalendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, monthOfYear);
            birthDataCalendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, dayOfMonth);
            updateLabel();
        }
    };

    if (getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("signInProfileImage") == null) {

        extra = getActivity().getIntent().getExtras();
        if (extra != null) {
            byteArray = extra.getByteArray("signUpProfileImage");
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(byteArray, 0, byteArray.length);
            civProfile.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }

    } else {
        String imagePath = getActivity().getIntent().getStringExtra("signInProfileImage");
        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(imagePath).into(civProfile);
    }

    etBirthDate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, birthDataCalendar
                    .get(Calendar.YEAR), birthDataCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                    birthDataCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH)).show();
        }
    });

    ivBack.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (getFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
                getFragmentManager().popBackStack();
            }
        }
    });
}


@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        for (Fragment fragment : getChildFragmentManager().getFragments()) {
            fragment.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        }
    }

    if (REQUEST_CAMERA == requestCode && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");

        ByteArrayOutputStream bytes = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        if (bitmap != null) {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, bytes);
        }
        String path = MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getActivity().getContentResolver(), bitmap, "", null);


        File filesDir = getActivity().getFilesDir();
        File imageFile = new File(filesDir, "image" + ".jpg");

        OutputStream os;
        try {
            os = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
            os.flush();
            os.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Error writing bitmap", e);
        }

        Uri.parse(path);

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(path).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().fit().into(civProfile);
    }

    if (requestCode == SELECT_FILE) {

        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Gallery clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        Uri selectedImageURI = data.getData();
        String filePath = getRealPathFromURIPath(selectedImageURI, getActivity());
        File file = new File(filePath);

        //RequestBody mFile = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/form-data"), file);


        try {
            InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            byte[] b = new byte[1024 * 8];
            int bytesRead = 0;

            while ((bytesRead = inputStream.read(b)) != -1) {
                bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Picasso.with(getActivity()).load(selectedImageURI).noPlaceholder().centerCrop().fit()
                .into((civProfile));
    }
}

private String getRealPathFromURIPath(Uri contentURI, Activity activity) {
    Cursor cursor = activity.getContentResolver().query(contentURI, null, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return contentURI.getPath();
    } else {
        cursor.moveToFirst();
        int idx = cursor.getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA);
        return cursor.getString(idx);
    }
}

private void updateLabel() {
    String myFormat = "dd-MMM-yyyy"; //In which you need put here
    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(myFormat, Locale.US);
    etBirthDate.setText(sdf.format(birthDataCalendar.getTime()));
  }
}
```

Initialisation in **MainActivity.java**

```
ivEditProfile.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            getSupportActionBar().hide();
            EditProfileFragment editProfileFragment = new EditProfileFragment();              
            FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.main_frame, editProfileFragment);
            transaction.addToBackStack(null);
            transaction.commit();
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        }
});
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: gallery is also taking you out of fragment or camera only?

Comment: @SachinVarma Gallery is also taking me out. The actual scenario is after returning back by selecting or capturing the image the activity is getting reinitialised and it loads from first fragment. I am trying to implement savedInstanceState to save the current fragment state when activity gets resumed.

Comment: @RakshitSorathiya 
you mean you lost data after selecting  image from gallery or camera ?

Comment: @RujulGandhi No there is no loss of data. But due to activity transactions the fragments inside that activity gets initialised from beginning that is from first fragment. After capturing the image from camera or selecting image from gallery I am required to stay on same fragment of activity.

Comment: Okay then show me your activity code where you trying to initialise your fragment !

Comment: @RujulGandhi Please refer the updated post to view declaration in MainActivity class

Comment: Okay @RakshitSorathiya , still i am a bit confused so can you please do one thing ,  post your whole fragment and main activity code on this `https://codeshare.io/rakhshit`.. So i will review it and will back to you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166313/discussion-between-rujul-gandhi-and-rakshit-sorathiya).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think as per your conversation(and my past experience). You have put something in `onResume()` like open your first fragment code, So you need to remove that code from `onResume()` and need to keep it at 'onCreate()' method in your activity.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, I realized that it is due to I have enabled following option:

```
Developer Options -> APPS -> Don't keep activities
```

I disable above option when testing image selection activity. And enable it back for other testings.